# Reverse DNS fail

Tags: linux, dns, bind

I have an installation of Zimbra 8.7 CS multi server

Server A: single-server installation (mail.jbv.cl 200.54.163.182) with two domains (jbv.cl and grupojbv.cl)

Server B: a second MTA (smtp.grupojbv.cl 200.54.163.179)

Server C: external dns (ns.jbv.cl 200.54.163.178)

I configured it this way since I need the mails from jbv.cl to exit from server A and the mails from grupojbv.cl to exit from server B.
The configuration works on the server without problem and each one uses the assigned mta, the problem is in my public DNS (ns.jbv.cl) which I manage, the point that does not solve the reverse of server B (smtp.grupojbv.cl)

If I make a query to the Google servers (8.8.8.8) throw me this:

**Dig -x 200.54.163.179 @8.8.8.8**

```
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;179.163.54.200.in-addr.arpa.   IN      PTR
;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
163.54.200.in-addr.arpa. 1799   IN      SOA     qip1.redip.cl. root.redip.cl. 2017062801 21600 3600 604800 86400
```

But if I do the same query my public dns throws this:

**Dig -x 200.54.163.179 @ns.jbv.cl**

```
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;179.163.54.200.in-addr.arpa.   IN      PTR
;; ANSWER SECTION:
179.163.54.200.in-addr.arpa. 38400 IN   PTR     smtp.grupojbv.cl.
;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
179.163.54.200.in-addr.arpa. 38400 IN   NS      ns.jbv.cl.
;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns.jbv.cl.              38400   IN      A       200.54.163.178
```

If I make the same query to (jbv.cl) returns the reverse without problems

What is the problem with my DNS? I've waited a week waiting for it to spread but nothing.

Here the configuration of my DNS server Ubuntu server 16.04

**Named.conf.local**

```
zone "jbv.cl" {
        type master;
        file "/var/lib/bind/jbv.cl.hosts";
        };
zone "grupojbv.cl" {
        type master;
        file "/var/lib/bind/grupojbv.cl.hosts";
        };
zone "163.54.200.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/var/lib/bind/200.54.163.rev";
        };
```

**/var/lib/bind/jbv.cl.hosts (jbv.cl)**

```
$ttl 38400
jbv.cl. IN      SOA     ns.jbv.cl. admin.jbv.cl. (
                        1500432573
                        10800
                        3600
                        604800
                        38400 )
jbv.cl.                 IN      NS      ns.jbv.cl.
www.jbv.cl.             IN      CNAME   jbv.cl.
jbv.cl.                 IN      MX      10      mail.jbv.cl.
jbv.cl.                 IN      A       200.54.163.181
ns.jbv.cl.              IN      A       200.54.163.178
mail.jbv.cl.    IN      A       200.54.163.182
```

**/var/lib/bind/grupojbv.cl.hosts (grupojbv.cl)**

```
$ttl 38400

grupojbv.cl.    IN      SOA     ns.jbv.cl. admin.jbv.cl. (
                        1500432643
                        10800
                        3600
                        604800
                        38400 )
grupojbv.cl.            IN      NS      ns.jbv.cl.
grupojbv.cl.            IN      MX      20 smtp.grupojbv.cl.
smtp.grupojbv.cl.       IN      A       200.54.163.179
```

**/var/lib/bind/200.54.163.rev**

```
$ttl 38400
jbv.cl.         IN      SOA      ns.jbv.cl. admin.jbv.cl. (
                        1501037500
                        10800
                        3600
                        604800
                        38400 )
163.54.200.in-addr.arpa.        IN      NS      ns.jbv.cl.
179.163.54.200.in-addr.arpa.    IN      PTR     smtp.grupojbv.cl.
182.163.54.200.in-addr.arpa.    IN      PTR     mail.jbv.cl.
```

**Why the other dns servers do not solve the reverse of smtp.grupojbv.cl**

Comment: Just use `179    IN      PTR     smtp.grupojbv.cl.` (instead of `179.163.54.200.in-addr.arpa.    IN      PTR     smtp.grupojbv.cl.`) in RR declaration.

Answer (score 1):

The main fault I see with your .in-addr.arpa ("reverse DNS") domain is that the [**SOA**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOA_Resource_Record) record is wrong.  You are declaring it to be the Start Of Authority record for the `jbv.cl.` domain, rather than for the `163.54.200.in-addr.arpa.` domain.

In `/var/lib/bind/200.54.163.rev`, you need to replace this:

```
jbv.cl.                   IN      SOA      ns.jbv.cl. admin.jbv.cl. (
```

with this:

```
163.54.200.in-addr.arpa.  IN      SOA      ns.jbv.cl. admin.jbv.cl. (
```

Or, better yet:

```
@    IN      SOA      ns.jbv.cl. admin.jbv.cl. (
```

`@` is an alias for the current `$ORIGIN` - `bind` knows what it is, you told it in `named.conf.local` when you defined the zone.  Also, you don't have to specify the FQDN for every entry - any unqualified or incompletely-qualified name (i.e. one that **doesn't** end with a `.`) has `$ORIGIN` appended to it.

If you want, you can explicitly define `$ORIGIN` at the top of the file.  That's optional, but serves nicely as self-documentation for the file.  Setting `$ORIGIN` is mostly used when defining a domain and one or more subdomains in the same zonefile, changing $ORIGIN as needed to change what gets appended to non-FQDN names.

See, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zone_file, which says:

> The zone file may also contain various directives that are marked with
>   a keyword starting with the dollar sign character. The most notable is
>   the $ORIGIN keyword, which specifies the starting point for the zone
>   in the DNS hierarchy. If this keyword is omitted from a zone file, the
>   origin is inferred by the server software from the reference to the
>   zone file in its server configuration.

Your `200.54.163.rev` "reverse DNS" zonefile should look like this:

```
$ORIGIN 163.54.200.in-addr.arpa.
$TTL 38400
@          IN      SOA     ns.jbv.cl. admin.jbv.cl. (
                   1501037500
                   10800
                   3600
                   604800
                   38400 )

@          IN      NS      ns.jbv.cl.

179        IN      PTR     smtp.grupojbv.cl.
182        IN      PTR     mail.jbv.cl.
```

That's much easier to read and to work with when making changes.

The same is true for your other domains.   Use `@` in the `SOA` and `NS` records and ditch the FQDN on the LHS of each record.

---

I **very strongly** recommend you do some more reading about DNS and Zone Files - whether you look after your own DNS servers or outsource them to someone else.  Understanding how DNS works is essential for anyone who manages a domain.

If you don't have a copy of the O'Reilly [DNS and Bind](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596100575.do) book (IMO an almost essential book for anyone working with DNS servers. Even a second-hand older edition is very much worth having if you can't get the latest edition - the latest I own is the 2nd Edition from 1997), start with the Wikipedia Zone File page I linked to above.